# How to execute sub-tasks in a SQL Procedure in parallel

Tags: sql, multithreading, sqlclr

I have a process that analyzes audit data from one system to build reporting data for another system.  There is a managing procedure that loops for each day to be analyzed and calls a entity specific procedure with the current iteration's day.  Some entities take less than a second to process while others can take minutes. Running serially as it does in t-sql the cpu utilization never crests above 8% on the 16-core server.  Each of the entity specific procedures are not dependent on the others, just that all of the entities for that day are complete before the next day is started.

My idea is to have a CLR managing procedure and start the longer running procedures for the day running on their own threads, then once the quick ones are done, Thread.Join() the long running threads to wait for all Entities to complete for that day before moving on to the next.

Below is my try as the simplest thing that could work for just one worker thread, and calling Start on that thread does not result in the static method being called.  I have set a break point in the HelloWorld method and it is never hit.

I have tried something very much like this in a console application and had it work as does calling it on the same thread in the commented out line at the start of AsyncHelloWorld.  Is there something about threading within SQL CLR Procedures that is different?

```
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static void AsyncHelloWorld()
    {
        // HelloWorld(SqlContext.Pipe);

        var worker = new Thread(HelloWorld);
        worker.Start(SqlContext.Pipe);
        worker.Join();
    }

    public static void HelloWorld(object o)
    {
        var pipe = o as SqlPipe;

        if (pipe != null)
            pipe.Send("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or just nothing happens?

Comment: The HelloWorld method is never called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely cannot do that. A SqlPipe is very strongly tied to the context of the thread you were invoked on. While you can, technically, launch threads from SQLCRL, these threads **must** do all interaction with the caller from the original thread. But even so, launching CLR threads inside the SQL hosted environment is a *very* bad idea (and I won't enter into details why).

Instead, separate your logic into procedures than can be invoked in parallel and invoke these procedures in parallel from the client. You can use [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) as a pattern of scheduling procedures to be launched in asynchronously and queue based activation has built-in support for parallelism via `MAX_QUEUE_READERS` setting.

But most likely your procedures do not need explicit parallelism. T-SQL loads than can benefit from explicit user controlled parallelism are so rare that is not worth mentioning (not to mention that pulling transactional semantics right across parallel tasks is beyond mere mortals). T-SQL can leverage internal statement parallelism for processing data in parallel, so there is never a need for explicit parallelism.

So better you explain what is that you're *really* trying to solve and perhaps we can help.

Comment: I am summarizing audit records into a reporting database to support "As Of" querying of the system being reported on.  The import process has 2 main phases, one pulls the new un-analyzed audit records from the source system, and the second calculates the summaries and transforms the data into the reportable entities.

Comment: This looks like a flavor of ETL. Have you considered SSIS?

Comment: I updated the description to add more background.  I don't have any experience with SSIS, are you able to start more than one procedure and get notification when they are done, thus to trigger the start of the next group?

Comment: With SSIS the transformations are done in SSIS, not in stored procedures. You should start reading from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141711.aspx

Comment: If not SSIS, then your stored procedure should be set oriented. Sounds like you are doing this whole processing row by painfully slow row. Use set oriented logic, it will automatically scale to all cores, as much as the IO subsystem can provide sufficient throughput.

Comment: I assure you that my procedures are set oriented.  After some work on properly indexing the audit data, the query plan for the individual reporting entity constructing procedures does not include parallelism.  The trick is that I have a collection of these entity building procedures that are called in turn from the managing procedure, thus it must wait for entity 1's proc to complete before calling entity 2's proc and so on.  Each proc is consuming only 1 core and I only need to wait for all of them to be done, it doesn't matter which order.  Thanks for the SSIS link, new skills are great.